# How to reposition a mc's children to line up and point in the same direction?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm using AS2 and I have a train that a person can dynamically build. The user clicks on an object on the stage and a duplicate is created. WHen the user clicks and drags that duplicate into another oject it snaps to the right of the target object and now and array is created or added to. So the user can basically build a train with how ever amount of cars (or children if you prefer).

One feature I've added is when the user clicks and releases on the parent and there is no change in the `_x` and `_y` coordinates the whole train will know line up and point in a new direction. so if they are all lined up and pointing to the 3 o'clock position and the user clicks the parent, the parent will point to the six o'clock position and the children will all line up to the 12 o'clock and all point to the six. If he user keeps clicking the whole train will keep rotating.

Here is the code I'm working with (hopefully it's enough):

```
function rotate(_index,_angle):Void
{
    for(var _i in _linkArray[_index])
    {
        var _mcy:Number    = this[_linkArray[_index][_i]]._y;
        var _mcx:Number    = this[_linkArray[_index][_i]]._x;
        var _degree:Number = Math.atan2(_mcy,_mcx)*(180/Math.PI) + _angle;
        /* if not the first element line up and rotate */ 
        if(_i != 0)
        {
            this[_linkArra[_index][_i]._rotation += _degree;
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully there is enough info.

**EDIT**

I wanted to try and clarify what I'm trying to achieve. I don't have an example, but to better explain. There's a  movieclip that resides in the library called "railcar". When the SWF is launched "railcar" is attached on to the stage and that object will now be the master to create an infinite amount of duplicates. The ultimate goal here is the user will use those duplicates to build a train for a training aid. So if the user wants to start building that train, they will take a duplicate and drag and drop that on top of another object and those two are now linked together. The user can do this and build a train as large as they want.

When building the train all the cars will be stacked to the right of each parent object like so: (the arrow indicated the direction and each o indicated a single car of the train)

```
ooo->
```

When the user clicks the first car the whole train is supposed to rotate to point in another direct, here's an example:

```
^
o
o
o
```

and when the front car is clicked again it will rotate again:

```
<-oooo
```

So if you have a train that is all lined up and pointing to the 3'oclock position and you want it to point to the 9 o'clock position, you will click the lead car two times (since each rotation is 90 degrees) and the whole train will rotate in that direction will pointing to the lead car.

I wish I hd an example, but I do not, so hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Having a hard time understanding what you're trying to accomplish. Perhaps a diagram or mockup would help?

Comment: Hey London, no problem. I was headed to a meeting and was a little rushed. Look for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

So if you're basing the angle on item '0', you're not keeping that around.  As you go through the loop, you're constantly using the current item 'i'.  Move the angle calculations outside the loop and assign them with 0.  You'll also have to adjust the x and y points of the cars, but that will be dependent on the direction.

```
function rotate(_index,_angle):Void {
    var _mcy:Number    = this[_linkArray[_index][0]]._y;
    var _mcx:Number    = this[_linkArray[_index][0]]._x;
    var _degree:Number = Math.atan2(_mcy,_mcx)*(180/Math.PI) + _angle;

    for(var _i in _linkArray[_index]) {
         /* if not the first element line up and rotate */ 
         if(_i != 0) {
            this[_linkArra[_index][_i]._rotation += _degree;
            // hypothetical hook code for a sprite attached to the car
            this[_linkArra[_index][_i]._x = this[_linkArra[_index][_i-1].hook._x;
            this[_linkArra[_index][_i]._y = this[_linkArra[_index][_i-1].hook._y;
         }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hey Gone, thanks for your time :) All the cars will now rotate, but they will not reposition in a single file line behind the lead car in the same direction. They always stay stacked up to the right of the lead car.

Comment: That's what I was saying.  You're going to need to calculate the new x,y pos for the cars.  Basically, determine the connection point of the previous car and set it the new car to that.  But positioning could get tricky and there are a number of ways to make this simpler without code.  Add a small 1x1 pixel sprite as a child of the car at the end of each car object and use that as the connection point. As long as the center of each car is positioned at the center front you can assign the previous car's 'hook' position to the current car's position and everything will fall into line.

Comment: You can also assign a hook point property to the car if you know ahead of time what it would be, which would work without adding an extra sprite.  The hard way would be to calculate the new x,y point based on the rotation.  Make it simple.  Good luck!

Comment: Added some sample code above as hypothetical - without knowing what you have, I can't do more than that.  Hopefully it gives you enough to work with.

Comment: Since this is AS2 - you might not not being using classes, so the 1x1 sprite might be the best option.  However, depending on your code, you'll need to access it appropriately - another array, perhaps.  My solution might not be usable as is.